# Name of exercise and muscles worked

Tags: muscle, workout-routines, strength-training

Is there a specific name for an exercise where you carry weights a small distance place them on the ground pick them up again and do the same.

Also, what major muscles would this exercise work out.

Comment: The name of the exercise that I believe you are talking about is the Farmer Walk. I think the more appropriate question is what muscles does the farmer walk not work out. It works out quads, hamstrings, glutes, calves, lats, erectors, traps, abs, biceps, triceps, forearms, hand muscles, and many smaller ones too. For the smaller ones, see this other question: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43616/which-muscles-do-loaded-carries-train-that-are-not-trained-by-other-compund-move

Comment: @EricWarburton -- I'd do a quick check to see if this is a duplicate, but if not, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a specific name for an exercise where you carry weights a small distance place them on the ground pick them up again and do the same?

There are several loaded carries which fit this description. The most common one is called a **[Farmer Walk](https://youtu.be/Fkzk_RqlYig?t=18)** where you hold a weight in each hand to your sides. Other variations include: [The Suitcase Carry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyK-synJ9fs), [Duck Walk](https://youtu.be/7sMCN9CJHJ4?t=4), [Zercher Walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVgZ8QOhh-U), [Bear Hug](https://youtu.be/yHDf9arp62k?t=8), and [Overhead Walk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1qx6m67T9A) just to name a few.

> Also, what major muscles would this exercise work out?

The Farmer Walk works out just about just about everything. It works out quads, hamstrings, glutes, calves, lats, erectors, traps, abs, biceps, triceps, forearms, hand muscles, and many smaller ones too. For the smaller ones, see this other [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43616/which-muscles-do-loaded-carries-train-that-are-not-trained-by-other-compund-move). Typically it is seen as a grip exercise though.

Other variations will largely work similar muscles, but maybe hit certain ones harder.

- Side loaded will be the most balanced lift.
- Front loaded are typically more taxing on your biceps.
- Overhead focus on shoulder and core stability.
- Duck walks will focus more on glutes.